# How to create a trigger with time range and week daysin Google ScriptApp

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to create a trigger in Google ScriptApp, where it triggers from Monday to Friday between 9AM to 5PM, is it possible?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `it triggers from Monday to Friday between 9AM to 5PM`. You want to execute a function at 9AM and 5PM from Monday to Friday? What mean of `between 9AM to 5PM`?

Comment: Yes, between 9am to 5pm from Monday to Friday , the trigger will be activate. E.g. if it sends notification , the function will only send notification like every half hour between 9am to 5 pm from Monday to Friday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure it's possible without manually creating a trigger for every hour of the day you want the function to run.

Why not use an hourly trigger, but automatically exit the triggered function if the current time is not a week day between 9 and 5pm?

```
function triggeredFunction() {
  const currentDate= new Date();
if(currentDate.getDay() < 1 ||  currentDate.getDay() > 5 || currentDate.getHours() < 9 || currentDate.getHours() > 17) 
return;


// your code
}
```